# Find a subdocument in array PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to query what comments have been made by any User about machine learning book between '2020-03-15' and '2020-04-25', ordered the comments from the most recent to the least recent.

Here is my document.

```
lib_books = db.lib_books
document_book1 = ({
    "bookid" : "99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0",
    "title" : "Machine learning",
    "author" : "Tom Michael",
    "date_of_first_publication" : "2000-10-02",
    "number_of_pages" : 414,
    "publisher" : "New York : McGraw-Hill",
    "topics" : ["Machine learning", "Computer algorithms"],
    "checkout_list" : [
    {
        "time_checked_out" : "2020-03-20 09:11:22",
        "userid" : "ef1234",
        "comments" : [
        {
            "comment1" : "I just finished it and it is worth learning!",
            "time_commented" : "2020-04-01 10:35:13"
        },
        {
            "comment2" : "Some cases are a little bit outdated.",
            "time_commented" : "2020-03-25 13:19:13"
        },
        {
            "comment3" : "Can't wait to learning it!!!",
            "time_commented" : "2020-03-21 08:21:42"
        }]
    },
    {
        "time_checked_out" : "2020-03-04 16:18:02",
        "userid" : "ab1234",
        "comments" : [
        {
            "comment1" : "The book is a little bit difficult but worth reading.",
            "time_commented" : "2020-03-20 12:18:02"
        },
        {
            "comment2" : "It's hard and takes a lot of time to understand",
            "time_commented" : "2020-03-15 11:22:42"
        },
        {
            "comment3" : "I just start reading, the principle of model is well explained.",
            "time_commented" : "2020-03-05 09:11:42"
        }]
    }]
})
```

I tried this code, but it returns nothing.

```
query_test = lib_books.find({"bookid": "99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0", "checkout_list.comments.time_commented" : {"$gte" : "2020-03-20", "$lte" : "2020-04-20"}})
for x in query_test:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{'bookid':"99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0"}},//bookid filter
            {'$unwind':'$checkout_list'},
            {'$unwind':'$checkout_list.comments'},
            {'$match':{'checkout_list.comments.time_commented':{"$gte" : "2020-03-20", "$lte" : "2020-04-20"}}},
            {'$project':{'_id':0,'bookid':1,'title':1,'comment':'$checkout_list.comments'}},
            {'$sort':{'checkout_list.comments.time_commented':-1}}]

query_test = lib_books.aggregate(pipeline)
#{"bookid": "99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0", "checkout_list.comments.time_commented" : {"$gte" : "2020-03-20", "$lte" : "2020-04-20"}})
for x in query_test:
    print(x)
```

I would recommend that you maintain comment field as one name, rather than keeping it as 'comment1', 'comment2', etc. If the field had been 'comment', it can be brought to the root itself

Aggregate can be modified as below

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{'bookid':"99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0"}},//bookid filter
            {'$unwind':'$checkout_list'},
            {'$unwind':'$checkout_list.comments'},
            {'$match':{'checkout_list.comments.time_commented':{"$gte" : "2020-03-20", "$lte" : "2020-04-20"}}},
            {'$project':{'_id':0,'bookid':1,'title':1,'comment':'$checkout_list.comments.comment','time_commented':'$checkout_list.comments.time_commented'}},
            {'$sort':{'time_commented':-1}}]
```

MongoDB Query, in case if required

```
db.books.aggregate([
{$match:{'bookid':"99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0"}},//bookid filter
{$unwind:'$checkout_list'},
{$unwind:'$checkout_list.comments'},
{$match:{'checkout_list.comments.time_commented':{"$gte" : "2020-03-20", "$lte" : "2020-04-20"}}},
{$project:{_id:0,bookid:1,title:1,comment:'$checkout_list.comments.comment',time_commented:'$checkout_list.comments.time_commented'}},
{$sort:{'time_commented':-1}}
])
```

if there are multiple documents that you need to search, then you can use `$in` condition.

```
{$match:{'bookid':{$in:["99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd0","99051fe9-6a9c-46c2-b949-38ef78858dd1"]}}},//bookid filter
```

Comment: Hi Abishek, it works! Thank you so much! Could you please tell me some resources of learning the aggregate query of PyMongo or MongoDB?

Comment: Also, what if there are many book documents and I want to filter the bookid field? Thank you!

Comment: @QinZ, you can learn more about MongoDB Aggregation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation)

I think I missed the bookid filter in the aggregation statement above. Let me edit my answer.